# Python: How to see which of several words matched?

Tags: python, regex

Here is a small artificial example:

```
s = 'I eat apple'
found = re.WHICH_ONE_MATCHED("\\b(?:banana|apple|carrot)\\b", s)
print "You like that "+found
```

How to do it right?

Comment: re.findall( "(banana|apple|carrots)", "I love apples" ) does the trick. Did you even bother looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = 'I eat apple carrot and banana'
found = re.findall("\\b(?:banana|apple|carrot)\\b", s)
print found
```

[**IDEONE DEMO**](http://ideone.com/9PN8ir)

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups for your search words in regex and then examine the captured groups in the result after call to `findall`. See these examples:

```
>>> s = 'I eat apple'
>>> arr = re.findall(r"\b(?:(banana)|(apple)|(carrot))\b", s)
[('', 'apple', '')]
>>> for v in arr:
...     print filter(None, v)[0]
...
apple


>>> s = 'I eat apple and carrot'
>>> arr = re.findall(r"\b(?:(banana)|(apple)|(carrot))\b", s)
>>> for v in arr:
...     print filter(None, v)[0]
...
apple
carrot
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I have the same output without empty strings?

Comment: You could have avoided capturing groups for `apple` etc

Comment: Reason why I didn't put them in same group is this. If input is `'I eat apple  and eat banana'` and OP wants a fruit name after word `eat` i.e. `r'eat (?:banana|apple|carrot)'` then single group will give `['eat apple', 'eat banana']` but my suggestion will still give `apple, banana` (but I may have overthought if OP's requirements are not such)

Comment: @anubhava Nice thinking

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using Counter(). The advantage is that you will know how many times the word is found.

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'I eat apple'
to_find = ['banana','apple','carrot']
found = Counter()

for word in s.split(' '):
    if word in to_find:
        found.update({word})

print(found)
>>> Counter({'apple': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this, you can simply store your fruit in a list then use the a for loop to find the match.

```
>>> s = 'I eat apple'
>>> fruits  = ['banana', 'apple', 'carrot']
>>> found = [fruit for fruit in fruits if fruit in s][0]
>>> print "You like that %s" %found
You like that apple
```